# How to open programs using AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey, notepad

I have the application called Manual Crimp OPEN.  on that app opened i want to press <kbd>F2</kbd> KEY on the keyboard to open another application called Rework Cables .but not to closed it but to switch between the two application ? is it possible using AutoHotKey ?

Any help will be highly appreciated ?

Comment: Do you want to switch between "Manual Crimp OPEN" and "Rework Cables"?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean switching between like you would do with[Alt]+[Tab].

Not sure how familiar you are with AutoHotKey but here is a start.

```
SetTitleMarchMode, 2

F2::
wingettitle, Title, A
IfInString, Title, Manual Crimp
{
  IfWinNotExist, Rework Cables
  {
    Run, C:\path\ReworkCables.exe
    WinWait, Rework Cables
  }
  WinActivate, Rework Cables
}
Else IfInString, Title, Rework Cables
  WinActivate, Manual Crimp OPEN
Else
  Send, {F2}
Return
```

P.s. I have not tested the code...